# How to set the page title in Vue 2, that will work on page load, from the component

Tags: vuejs2, seo, accessibility, vue-router

I am trying to set the page title from the component as there are dynamic properties that will change the content of the title.

Using the examples I have found on here talk about setting the `this.$route.meta.pageTitle`. This only works when the page is navigated to via the application, not on a page refresh or load from bookmark.

I have tried to hook into all the lifecycle hooks, both in the router and the component, as well as adding a watcher in my root component.

How do I set the title on those load conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the component, you need to set the `document.title` rather than the route metadata.

```
created () {
    this.$route.meta.title = `${myDynamicProp} - my site`
    document.title = this.$route.meta.title;
}
```